# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp] in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, postgresql-9.2

I have my code deployed in Tomcat 6.0.32 at my local machine at windows environment. And the same WAR file is deployed in Tomcat 7.0.39 at remote machine at linux environment.

Code for context.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/CentralizedPush">
        <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/postgres" password="commonpush12#" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://10.40.5.59:5444/commonpush_database" username="commonpush"/>
    </Context>
```

The code for DBConnection.java is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;  


public class DBConnection {
    private static Connection con = null;

/**function is used for creating connection
 * @return Connection object
 */
public static Connection getConnection() {
    org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Error");

    try {
        Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName(Constant.CLASS_NAME).newInstance();
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/postgres");

        con = ds.getConnection();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("ClassNotFoundException" );
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("InstantiationException" );
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("IllegalAccessException" );
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("NamingException" );
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("SQLException in db connection" );
    }

    return con;
}
```

I have database in postgres that I am trying to access whose details are as follows:

```
Name: CDCUCOMPUDB
Host: 10.40.5.59
Port: 5444
database name: commonpush_database
```

The problem is when I deploy the code at my local machine everything is fine, but when I deploy the code at remote server which is in Linux environment and has the different Tomcat version I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
```

Kindly suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a single lookup of "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres". There's no reason to use two Contexts here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I was trying to create a global jdbc connection pool, following instructions [Tomcat DataSource JNDI Example for Servlet Web Application](http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-for-servlet-web-application). In his example code he used "java:/comp/" to look up, not "java:comp/". This is problematic. Otherwise, a very helpful guide.